# Nuxt.js plugin works only after refresh

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In Nuxt I am trying to use retina.js to display @2x size of images. It is working but only after refreshing the page. There are even no errors in console, just image in normal size. This is my plugins in nuxt.config.js:

```
  plugins: [
    {src: 'plugins/owl.js', ssr: false},
    {src: 'plugins/retina.js'},
  ],
```

Here is Retina.js plugin:

```
(function() {
    var root = (typeof exports === 'undefined' ? window : exports);
    var config = {
        // An option to choose a suffix for 2x images
        retinaImageSuffix : '@2x',

        // Ensure Content-Type is an image before trying to load @2x image
        // https://github.com/imulus/retinajs/pull/45)
        check_mime_type: true,

        // Resize high-resolution images to original image's pixel dimensions
        // https://github.com/imulus/retinajs/issues/8
        force_original_dimensions: true
    };

    function Retina() {}

    root.Retina = Retina;

    Retina.configure = function(options) {
        if (options === null) {
            options = {};
        }

        for (var prop in options) {
            if (options.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                config[prop] = options[prop];
            }
        }
    };

    Retina.init = function(context) {
        if (context === null) {
            context = root;
        }

        var existing_onload = context.onload || function(){};

        context.onload = function() {
            var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'), retinaImages = [], i, image;
            for (i = 0; i < images.length; i += 1) {
                image = images[i];
                if (!!!image.getAttributeNode('data-no-retina')) {
                    retinaImages.push(new RetinaImage(image));
                }
            }
            existing_onload();
        };
    };

    Retina.isRetina = function(){
        var mediaQuery = '(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)';

        if (root.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
            return true;
        }

        if (root.matchMedia && root.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    };


    var regexMatch = /\.\w+$/;
    function suffixReplace (match) {
        return config.retinaImageSuffix + match;
    }

    function RetinaImagePath(path, at_2x_path) {
        this.path = path || '';
        if (typeof at_2x_path !== 'undefined' && at_2x_path !== null) {
            this.at_2x_path = at_2x_path;
            this.perform_check = false;
        } else {
            if (undefined !== document.createElement) {
                var locationObject = document.createElement('a');
                locationObject.href = this.path;
                locationObject.pathname = locationObject.pathname.replace(regexMatch, suffixReplace);
                this.at_2x_path = locationObject.href;
            } else {
                var parts = this.path.split('?');
                parts[0] = parts[0].replace(regexMatch, suffixReplace);
                this.at_2x_path = parts.join('?');
            }
            this.perform_check = true;
        }
    }

    root.RetinaImagePath = RetinaImagePath;

    RetinaImagePath.confirmed_paths = [];

    RetinaImagePath.prototype.is_external = function() {
        return !!(this.path.match(/^https?\:/i) && !this.path.match('//' + document.domain) );
    };

    RetinaImagePath.prototype.check_2x_variant = function(callback) {
        var http, that = this;
        if (this.is_external()) {
            return callback(false);
        } else if (!this.perform_check && typeof this.at_2x_path !== 'undefined' && this.at_2x_path !== null) {
            return callback(true);
        } else if (this.at_2x_path in RetinaImagePath.confirmed_paths) {
            return callback(true);
        } else {
            http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            http.open('HEAD', this.at_2x_path);
            http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (http.readyState !== 4) {
                    return callback(false);
                }

                if (http.status >= 200 && http.status <= 399) {
                    if (config.check_mime_type) {
                        var type = http.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
                        if (type === null || !type.match(/^image/i)) {
                            return callback(false);
                        }
                    }

                    RetinaImagePath.confirmed_paths.push(that.at_2x_path);
                    return callback(true);
                } else {
                    return callback(false);
                }
            };
            http.send();
        }
    };


    function RetinaImage(el) {
        this.el = el;
        this.path = new RetinaImagePath(this.el.getAttribute('src'), this.el.getAttribute('data-at2x'));
        var that = this;
        this.path.check_2x_variant(function(hasVariant) {
            if (hasVariant) {
                that.swap();
            }
        });
    }

    root.RetinaImage = RetinaImage;

    RetinaImage.prototype.swap = function(path) {
        if (typeof path === 'undefined') {
            path = this.path.at_2x_path;
        }

        var that = this;
        function load() {
            if (! that.el.complete) {
                setTimeout(load, 5);
            } else {
                if (config.force_original_dimensions) {
                    that.el.setAttribute('width', that.el.offsetWidth);
                    that.el.setAttribute('height', that.el.offsetHeight);
                }

                that.el.setAttribute('src', path);
            }
        }
        load();
    };


    if (Retina.isRetina()) {
        Retina.init(root);
    }
})();
```

Is it even posible to run retina.js as plugin like that in Nuxt? 
Thank you for help!

Comment: Could you share `plugins/retina.js` file?

Comment: This is not a nuxt plugin and it will not work with ssr - add `{src: 'plugins/retina.js', ssr: false}` Client side it should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for help but I've already tried ssr: false. Same problem :/